# IN c# how to get file names starting with a prefix from resource folder

Tags: c#, resources

how to access a text file based on its prefix

```
var str = GrvGeneral.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(configFile + "_Nlog_Config");
var str1  = GrvGeneral.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(configFile + "_Nlog_Config");
```

where the configfile is the prefix of the resourcefile A & B .

Based on the configfile contents (prefix) the resource file A & B has to be accessed .

Comment: What is wrong with your code? It loads resources based on the given names.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `DirectoryInfo` class ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx)). Then you can call the `GetFiles` with a search pattern.

```
string searchPattern = "abc*.*";  // This would be for you to construct your prefix

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path\To\Your\Dir");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(searchPattern);
```

**Edit:** If you have a way of constructing the actual file name you're looking for, you can go directly to the [FileInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), otherwise you'll have to iterate through the matching files in my previous example.

Comment: I have added the resources in the proeprties , resources to the project. So there is a.nlog.config file and b.config.file I. I have a method That access these with a prefix passed by a method . so I wanted to access the text , In these config files . so I cant follow how the code above will help me ?

Comment: I'm thinking that I don't really understand your original question because I don't understand what you just asked me there. Are you asking how to reference a resource file based on a setting in a configuration file?

Comment: no  I wanted to access a resource file and assign its text contents to a var .

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather vague...but it sounds like you want to get the text contents of an embedded resource. Usually you would do that using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`. You can always use LINQ along with `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` to find the name of an embedded file matching a pattern.

The `ResourceManager` class is more often used for automatically retrieving localized string resources, such as labels and error messages in different languages.

update: A more generalized example:

```
internal static class RsrcUtil {
    private static Assembly _thisAssembly;
    private static Assembly thisAssembly {
        get {
            if (_thisAssembly == null) { _thisAssembly = typeof(RsrcUtil).Assembly; }
            return _thisAssembly;
        }
    }

    internal static string GetNlogConfig(string prefix) {
        return GetResourceText(@"Some\Folder\" + prefix + ".nlog.config");
    }

    internal static string FindResource(string pattern) {
        return thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
               .FirstOrDefault(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern));
    }

    internal static string GetResourceText(string resourceName) {
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resourceName) != null) {
            using (Stream stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
                result = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Using the example:

```
string aconfig = RsrcUtil.GetNlogConfig("a");
string bconfigname = RsrcUtil.FindResource(@"b\.\w+\.config$");
string bconfig = RsrcUtil.GetResourceText(bconfigname);
```